# How to make Android touch and hold process repeatedly

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android long-touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553163/android-long-touch-event)

See screenshot:

[image]

Standard deal. Two buttons and TextView.
I handle OnClick for button and value goes up/down all works nice.

Would be even nicer if I can code "OnPressAndHold" and update UI with incremental time periods. Like on TimePicker when you click and hold it would increment/decrement values repeatedly. Any pointers?

Comment: A simple pointer: override onTouch, use a thread/timed message/etc so that every x ms you increment. Start the thread/etc on down, then stop at up.

Comment: You should be able to use the long press event with a while loop: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html Not sure off hand how to tell when the user has lifted their finger, but something like this post should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272409/stop-onlongclicklistener-from-firing-while-dragging