# Android how to disable View.OnLongClickListener programatically

Tags: android

In app I have RecyclerView with views that has `View.OnLongClickListener`. On parent GroupView I set onTouch listener, so I can detect swipe movement. Problem is that I can't prevent LongPress from firing while I have swipe action. My touch interceptor for GroupView

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        listener.onTouchIntercept(event);
        if (proceedTouchEventToChild) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use `view.setOnLongClickListener(null);` on your touch event

Comment: Try this SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6282221/4291272